# Call a javascript function in select tag of html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file (country.js) which has some function written like getcountry() and setcountry() etc. getCountry has the list of all the countries. Now I want to use this function to show all countries in a combo-box on my web page. but I do not how to call this function in html section.

this is some part of country.js file.

```
 ------------------Country.js--------------------------   
function _getCountries() {

}

function _setCountries() {
    _countries.push({ CountryID: 1, Name: 'Germany' });
    _countries.push({ CountryID: 2, Name: 'India' });
    _countries.push({ CountryID: 3, Name: 'China' });
    .................................................
}
```

I am trying something like that but do not know how to use this function in html part. I am new on web development.

```
      -------------HTML--------------------------
      <div>
    <select onchange="Country()">
    
    //what to do in this section?
    </select>
   </div>

     ___________ javaScript__________________
    function Country{

           getCountries();
       //what to do in this section?
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

`_countries` is an array which contains all your object.

make `_countries` to global variable and use in

```
function _getCountries() {
   return _countries;
}
```

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

//Create array of options to be added
var array = [{ CountryID: 1, Name: 'Germany' },{ CountryID: 2, Name: 'India' },{ CountryID: 3, Name: 'China' }];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
    option.text = array[i].Name+"-"+array[i].CountryID;
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Append here</div>
```